# Using Im[] and Re[] Correctly

Tags: complex

Hi I just want to check my code is working properly as I am trying to rule out any errors.

I'm integrating 4 coupled ODE's that have real and imaginary terms, so I have 8 equations.

The section of code I'm worried about is where I separate real and imaginary terms.

```
dkai1BYdx3 = ComplexExpand[Delta1*kai1 + Delta2*kai3];
Kai1REAL = Re[dkai1BYdx3];
Kai1IMAG = Im[dkai1BYdx3];
```

Will this code separate the real and imaginary parts of dkaiBYdx3 correctly? It contains non trivial functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Re` and `Im` make no assumptions about the domain of unbound symbols, so using them by themselves like this will not do what you appear to want. On the other hand, `ComplexExpand` assumes unbound symbols represent real numbers, and has rules to rewrite `Re`and `Im`. So, put them in the expression you're expanding:

```
Kai1REAL = ComplexExpand[Re[dkai1BYdx3]];
Kai1IMAG = ComplexExpand[Im[dkai1BYdx3]];
```

Comment: +1 For convenience one can also write `{Kai1REAL, Kai1IMAG} = ComplexExpand[ReIm[dkai1BYdx3]]` (V10.1 and upwards) or `{Kai1REAL, Kai1IMAG} = ComplexExpand[Through[{Re,Im}[dkai1BYdx3]]]` (before Version 10.1).